# listview onItemClick not firing

Tags: android, listview

I have two listviews in one activity. I set adapters for each.

This is what I have:

```
  lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
            R.layout.custom_list_item_1, classesBradycardia));
            specialist.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                    R.layout.custom_list_item_1, specialistBradycardia));
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String selectedVal = //((TextView) v).getText().toString();
            lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    Log.d(selectedVal, "it's in " + selectedVal);
    final int result = 1;
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.lvSpecificTest:
        if(selectedVal.equals("Electrocardiogram")){
            Intent ecg = new Intent(this, ViewTest.class);
            extras.putString("viewtest", "Electrocardiogram");
            ecg.putExtras(extras);
            startActivityForResult(ecg, result);
```

I put Log in it. It's showing the selected item but it's not going to the next Activity. What am I missing here?

Comment: Does the root layout in `custom_list_item_1.xml` have the id `@+id/lvSpecifciText`? And does `selectVal` actually equal `"Electrocardiogram"` (use the debugger for this)?

Comment: it only has a textview = @android:id/text1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it only has a textview = @android:id/text1

Your switch statement will never run because the ids don't match...

```
switch(v.getId()){
case R.id.lvSpecificTest:  // Does not equal android.R.id.text1
```

---

**Addition**

> in my main layout i have 2 listviews, one is named lvSpecificTest?

The second parameter `v` refers to the row, i.e. `R.layout.custom_list_item_1`, not the ListView. The first parameter `parent` refers to the ListView. Try:

```
switch(parent.getId()){
case R.id.lvSpecificTest:
```

Comment: in my main layout i have 2 listviews, one is named lvSpecificTest?

Comment: oh I see. so I will change v to parent.

Comment: Pal you're such a great teacher! For explaining between parameter v and parent. I never knew that until you explained. Thanks so much!